# How to extract json data from the Url using powershell script

Tags: json, powershell

I want my data from the url and want to filer it accordingly and export that data into  the csv file
This is my code
Here $url variable contains the url

```
$defs = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($url) -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials)

$json = convertto-Json $defs

$json | Out-File  D:\My_scripts\Final.json


$a = Get-Content D:\My_scripts\Final.json -raw | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

$arrOutput = @()

foreach($l2 in $a)
{
   foreach($l3 in $l2.value)
   {
      #Write-Host $l3.id
       $arr = @{}
       $arr.id = $l3.id
       $arr.name = $l3.name

       $outarray = New-Object Psobject -Property $arr

       $arrOutput += $outarray

   }
} 
$arrOutput | Export-Csv -Path D:\My_scripts\Final.csv -Delimiter  "," -NoTypeInformation
```

But not able to get the values

Comment: Can you post a (cut down) example of your Final.json? Also, is there a reason why you export ```$defs``` to a file and then read it back in to ```$a```? Can you not just do ```foreach($l2 in $defs)```

Comment: What version of powershell are you using? Powershell v7+ has many fixes and improvements specifically for handling json, so it may be helpful to you.